# SVG - how to combine multiple paths

Tags: javascript, xml, svg

Am wondering how can we combine multiple svg paths to a single path so that fill like operation can be done.

my svg

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<svg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'  width='227.178pt' height='191.646pt' viewBox='0 -191.646 227.178 191.646'>
<g id='page1' >
<g transform='matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 0)'>

<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M5.769237 179.523834C5.769237 181.433821 6.526939 183.265855 7.878501 184.613448C9.226377 185.965009 11.058411 186.722994 12.968398 186.722994" stroke="#ff0ef4" fill="none" stroke-width=".720001" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M5.769237 179.523834V11.753911" stroke="#ff0ef4" fill="yellow" stroke-width=".720001" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M13.027075 4.988281C11.116805 4.988281 9.28477 5.746094 7.933209 7.097658C6.585617 8.44922 5.827915 10.277342 5.827915 12.187499" stroke="#ff0ef4" fill="none" stroke-width=".720001" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M214.210917 4.921875H13.027075" stroke="#ff0ef4" fill="none" stroke-width=".720001" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M221.41016 12.121112C221.41016 10.214838 220.648441 8.382804 219.300783 7.031254C217.949225 5.67969 216.11719 4.921875 214.210917 4.921875" stroke="#ff0ef4" fill="none" stroke-width=".720001" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M221.41016 179.523834V12.121112" stroke="#ff0ef4" fill="none" stroke-width=".720001" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M214.210917 186.722994C216.11719 186.722994 217.949225 185.965009 219.300783 184.613448C220.648441 183.265855 221.41016 181.433821 221.41016 179.523834" stroke="#ff0ef4" fill="none" stroke-width=".720001" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M214.210917 186.722994H12.968398" stroke="#ff0ef4" fill="none" stroke-width=".720001" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

i tried to combine  path data like this but it messed up the shape

```xml
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M5.769237 179.523834 C5.769237 181.433821 6.526939 183.265855 7.878501 184.613448 C9.226377 185.965009 11.058411 186.722994 12.968398 186.722994 V11.753911 C11.116805 4.988281 9.28477 5.746094 7.933209 7.097658 C6.585617 8.44922 5.827915 10.277342 5.827915 12.187499 H13.027075 C221.41016 10.214838 220.648441 8.382804 219.300783 7.031254 C217.949225 5.67969 216.11719 4.921875 214.210917 4.921875 V12.121112 C216.11719 186.722994 217.949225 185.965009 219.300783 184.613448 C220.648441 183.265855 221.41016 181.433821 221.41016 179.523834 H12.968398 z" stroke="#ff0ef4" fill="yellow" stroke-width=".720001" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
```

my goal is to combine them so that i can fill inside of the shape. so any idea how to to do it properly or any there is js/php library which can do it

Comment: Instead of trying to join all those paths (you would need to change the order and the direction of some of them) try using a rectangle with rounded corners. An equivalent to what you have would be `<rect y="-187" x="5" width="216" height="183" rx="10"/>`

Comment: @enxaneta ya manually can create rect shape the way u suggested , however i get those paths from pdf export to svg , so i have to automate it

Comment: As I've commented before: in order to connect those paths you will need to reverse some of them and to change the order of the paths. A solution would be to use the bounding box of the page1 group (page1.getBBox())  to draw the rectangle.

Comment: How general a solution are you looking for? As enxneta says, the problem is that the first two corners are drawn in the wrong direction - which you can see if you add markers to each line segment (https://codepen.io/mullany/pen/bfc6e17c4a8ac7805e9cb9a5b334c49e) - You can fix this by swapping the Moveto (M) coordinates and the destination coordinates (the first pair) of the Curveto (C) path commands for those paths.

Comment: @MichaelMullany thanks i will try with swapping Moveto (M) coordinates with destination

Comment: @MichaelMullany i swapped it but seems am not doing it right , can u please review these two formats for first path i swapped 

`M7.878501 184.613448 C5.769237 181.433821 6.526939 183.265855 5.769237 179.523834 C9.226377 185.965009 11.058411 186.722994 5.769237 179.523834`
 second  
`M12.968398 186.722994 C5.769237 181.433821 6.526939 183.265855 5.769237 179.523834 C9.226377 185.965009 11.058411 186.722994 5.769237 179.523834`